# Modifying a string while looping on it

Tags: python, string, loops, immutability

Here we modify the string `s` while looping on it:

```
s = 'hello'
for c in s:
    s += c
    print(s)
```

It doesn't generate an infinite loop (it *could*: we add a new character in each iteration!).

I know this since years, but I can't really explain why. Has this something to do with string immutability or is it not related?

When doing `for c in s:`, **is the original `s` copied in memory before starting the loop?**

---

Another case that I thought could generate an infinite loop, but it does not:

```
s = 'hello'
def f(x):
    i = 0
    while True:
        try:
            yield x[i]
        except IndexError:
            break
        i += 1

for c in f(s):
    s += c
    print(s)
```

Comment: You are correct.  It iterates over the original object.  Rebinding the name to a new object doesn't change the for-loop because it doesn't resolve the name on each iteration.

Comment: `f(s)` is evaluated only once, during the start of the loop. It creates a generator using the initial string object. Subsequent re-assignment of `s` to some other object in `s += c` do not effect the original object since `+=` creates a new `str` object

Comment: `from itertools import cycle;for c in cycle('hello') # loop forever`

Comment: @rdas Yes, my example with `def f(x): return x` was irrelevant because the output is evaluated once, before the loop; I modified with a `yield`, here it could be more problematic!

Comment: official `for` loop documentation may [help](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/compound_stmts.html#for)

Answer (score 3):

> It doesn't generate an infinite loop (it could: we add a new character in each iteration!).

It is because [strings](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#text-sequence-type-str) in Python are immutable. 
When you do `for c in s`, `for` loop iterates over original object (object containing `"hello"`) and when you do `s += c`, a new string is created and hence, you aren't modifying the original string object that `for` loop is still iterating over.

Also, adding @Steven Rumbalski 's comment in my answer:

> It iterates over the original object. Rebinding the name to a new object doesn't change the for-loop because it doesn't resolve the name on each iteration.

Now, Let's talk about second example of yours:

If you call your function `f(s)`, it makes it's formal argument `x` to point to the object containing the string "hello" and it creates a generator using the string object. Now, subsequent re-assignment of the string `s` (using `s += c`) actually creates another string and doesn't effect the original object. Your function's formal argument is still pointing to an object containing `"hello"`.

So, after first iteration of your for loop in the second example:

1. Formal argument of function `f(x)` will be still pointing to an object containing "hello".
2. s will be pointing to an object containing `"helloh"`.

**IMPORTANT:**

However, if you try your code with mutable data types, it may create an infinite loop. See this:

```
li = [ 1, 2, 3, 4 ]
for i in li:
    li.append(i)
    print(li)
```

Answer (score 1):

Mutate a list to accomplish what you want.

```
array = list('hello')
for c in array:
    array.append(c)
    print(*array, sep='')
```

prints

```
helloh
hellohe
hellohel
hellohell
hellohello
hellohelloh
hellohellohe
hellohellohel
hellohellohell
hellohellohello
hellohellohelloh
hellohellohellohe
...
```

If you want to loop by one character continuously you can do

```
from itertools import cycle

for c in cycle('hello'):
    print(c)
```

prints

```
h
e
l
l
o
h
e
l
...
```

Answer (score 0):

This is not a recursive method. It is perfectly fine. It will run only once because you pass a string `f('hello')` now loop has "hello" to iterate. so it will run only once

Comment: Thank you for your answer. (I slightly modified the question). Can you add more details?

Comment: Yes, and here is your answer. The second one is a Generator function. A generator function is one that generates a sequence. When you call a generator function it gives you one element from the sequence and when you call it again, it will give you the next item of the sequence. You have created a generator function and in for loop you call it at once f(s) So this will not be infinite because it will return "hello" and loop will execute only once similarly as in the previous case